# Grails formRemote disabled field content isn't coming back as a param from GSP

Tags: grails

I am showing a text field on a GSP template that is in a formRemote and has content auto populated and is disabled (no editing allowed to user). When the form is submitted, I don't see the content of this field among the params going to the controller. I do see it when I remove the `disabled="true"` attribute from the text field. Any way to resolve this? Here is the field in question:

```
<label>Secondary ID:</label>&nbsp<g:textField name="secondaryId" disabled="true" style="border-radius: 5px" value="${recordToEdit ? recordToEdit.secondaryId : '' }"></g:textField>
```

Comment: Disabled fields do not get submitted by the browser. You will need to enable it prior to submitting the form if you need it to be sent.

Comment: @Joshua Moore I see. Thanks. Enabling it prior to form submission via Javascript is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly what I meant. You should also consider moving away from formRemote and other remote based tags as they are going away in Grails 3.x. Though they will likely be moved to a plugin once they are removed from the core.

Comment: @Joshua Moore Yes, I have been seeing that deprecation warning highlighted when I browse around the Grails documentation. If you wish to post your answer as an answer(as opposed to a comment). I'd be happy to mark correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled form elements do not get submitted by the browser. You will need to enable the field(s) (through use of Javascript) prior to submitting the form.